# Failing to boot Kali on B+ model Pi

Tags: sd-card

I have tried 2-3 times to follow instructions similar to this post :

http://docs.kali.org/armel-armhf/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi

EXCEPT I have only a class 4 SD Card on hand.

source image is at http://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/

My problem is, I plug everything in, put in the power and... one quick green LED, then solid red.  No Screen, no terminal, nothing.

Should I try again, or is class 10 really the only way to get this particular distro to load?

I've successfully used this same card over and over again, using NOOBS to install Debian.

**Update/Edit** : turns out I may need to revert the kernel back .. and load from the ARM image..

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=82931

This is for the B+ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update/Edit : turns out I may need to revert the kernel back .. and load from the ARM image..

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=82931

This is for the B+ only.

```
git clone https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-arm-build-scripts
cd kali-arm-build-scripts
sed -i 's/3.13.y/3.12.y/g' rpi.sh
./build-deps.sh
yes "" | ./rpi.sh 1.3.3.7
```

After it's done building the compressed image will be located at kali-arm-build-scripts/rpi-1.3.3.7/kali-1.3.3.7-rpi.img.xz

Comment: Can this be done from  a mac?

Comment: I believe I did this on OSX, yes.. been a while but `sed` might be the only question mark part of the commands